# What is the meaning of "subjects"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> His Holiness has issued the bull. It deprives Elizabeth, the pretended
>   Queen of England, servant of wickedness,  of her throne, and declares
>   that henceforth her **subjects** are absolved of their allegiance to her.

I find this lines in *Elizabeth (1998)* movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a *subject* as a [type of British nationality](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-subject)

> - Until 1949, nearly everyone with a close connection to the United Kingdom was called a ‘British subject’.
> - All citizens of Commonwealth countries were British subjects until January 1983.
> - Since 1983, very few people have qualified as British subjects.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary definition will provide the answer; A quick google search will yield this:

"a member of a state other than its ruler, especially one owing allegiance to a monarch or other supreme ruler."

It basically means the citizens under the power of a king/queen.

Hope this helps :)